# SKView.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ios8

I am not sure why, but when I move out my SKSpriteNodes from the visible area of the stage the frame drops to 12fps from 60.

If I set the shouldCullNonVisibleNodes property to NO then no culling functionality is enabled and I get the stable 60 fps.

My question is do you know any property or workaround to disable culling in iOS7 as shouldCullNonVisibleNodes is only available in iOS8 or later?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Kind regards,
Zsolt

Comment: There's no way to do that in iOS 7. Are you testing on simulator or device? How many sprite nodes are we talking about?

Comment: I tested it using the actual device. I think the SKShapeNodes cause this strange anomaly

Comment: I have around 16 nodes, so it shouldn't be the problem.
Somewhere I have read that, if the SKShapeNode is removed from the stage by the automatic culling it freezes the app and it looks like I have that case.

Comment: Do your SKShapeNodes change ? If not, you might try and wrap them in a `SKEffectNode` and enable the `shouldRasterize` property to flatten them. Another option is to convert them to a `SKTexture` via `textureFromNode`method of your scene. Then you can make the into a `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: Your question says SKSpriteNodes, and your comment says SKShapeNodes. Which is it ?

Comment: I have SKSpriteNodes and inside them there are SKShapeNodes

Comment: shouldRasterize is a good idea. I will give it a try.